# Can I say "providing that I'm a newcomer?"

Tags: grammaticality

I would like know if its grammatically correct to say '*Where am I supposed to submit my homework* ***providing that** I am a newcomer?*'(= that I'm new, I don't know where to submit the homework) Or can I use **'providing the fact'** or **'due to the fact that'** instead of saying **"*providing that*"** in the above sentence?

Comment: You want 'given that ...'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd write “… **provided** that I'm a newcomer.”, because that means that this is assumed by the public, or a **neccessary requirement.**

The other expressions make no sense to me; you are **not providing anything** simply by being a newcomer nor are you submitting your homework **just because** you're a newcomer.

I hope that helps; I'm very certain my answer is right, although I can't substantiate it…